# How to display <returns> contents when browsing code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xml-documentation

When hovering mouse pointer over a method in text editor, a tooltip appears displaying the method's signature along with `<summary>` xml-documentation element contents.

Also, when placing cursor before a parameter, it's possible to display corresponding `<param>` element contents along with method signature.

There is another useful xml tag: `<returns>`, but i can't figure out how to display it when browsing the code.

It's possible to display the entire method's documentation in ReSharper with "Edit\Show Quick Documentation..." feature

Is it possible to display the returns tag contents along with the description contents in Visual Studio without using a third-party tool?

Comment: I am sure it used to display it when you hover over the method name, however that doesn't appear to work in VS2012. Maybe they took it out for some reason after VS2010

Answer (score 0):

This will Show in Visual Studio intellisense.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Data Passed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="X"></param>
    /// <returns>Data Passed</returns>
    int GetData(int X)
    {
        return X;
    }
```

Comment: Not for me in VS2012 it doesn't

Comment: Are you sure both the summary and the returns are showing?

Comment: vs is showing the returns in object browser along with summary & parameters